# Cordova plugin background mode : onactivate is not working the first time (android)

Tags: javascript, cordova, background, ionic-framework, background-mode

I'm trying to use the background mode plugin in my ionic application but i'm encountering an issue.

I would like to do the same thing that what is shown in the readme of the github project with `backgroundmode.onactivate`.
It would work perfectly fine if it was not working only from the second time I go to background.

If anyone has any idea about that issue, I'd be glad to hear about it :)

Sample from my code :

```
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
 // Android customization
 cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ text:'Doing heavy tasks.'});
 // Enable background mode
 cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

 if(cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.isEnabled()){
     console.log('Hi, I am enabled. Signed : backgroundMode.');
   }

 // Called when background mode has been activated
 cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {
     setTimeout(function () {
         // Modify the currently displayed notification
         cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.configure({
             text:'Running in background for more than 5s now.'
         });
         console.log('Running in background for more than 5s now.');
     }, 5000);
 }
}, false);
```

Note : I do get the line `Hi, I am enabled. Signed : backgroundMode.` when my application is launched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the way of doing things to get round the problem. I did not manage to understand that bug though :(

```
document.addEventListener("pause",onPause,false);

function onPause() {
  $timeout(function() {
    console.log("Running in background for more than 5s now ...");
  }, 5000);

};
```

Comment: Hi, i´m also having trouble with that plugin you have talked about, and i can see that you have used this onPause function after...is that working for you? do you still have any kind of plugin in your xml file for background mode? or that onPause function is enought?

Comment: It worked perfectly fine with that onPause. I did not have many things to launch though.